# How can I get my python interpreter in PyCharm working again?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to IntelliJ products.

I have used PyCharm for two days and everything was fine, but from today I can not run my code because it just can not apply interpreter settings.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to launch a script file in PyCharm is to right-click it in the **Project** Tool Window (normally this is docked to the left as a sidebar or should open with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or from the **View** menu **→ Tool Windows**) and then select **Run** from the script file's context menu.

This will automatically generate a run configuration that will show up in the drop-down menu next to the Run button in the toolbar.

Comment: Yes, but actually i want to figure out why have that happend. It used to work from the creating of project

Comment: Actually there is no default run configuration when you create a new project. Did you maybe import an existing project that came with the configuration already?